# Can the Shimano front derailleur prevent a gear of my bike from working?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, repair

I recently bought a used rigid mountain bike, I'm very happy with it but I realized yesterday that I couldn't access the smallest chainring.

This one has a total of 3 front gears, but only numbers 2 and 3 are accessible.

I tried to adjust the Shimano but nothing works, I can't use chainring 1. *(I am a beginner not an expert)*

Can the problem come from the Shimano? Should I look at something else?

*Note: bike reference: B'TWIN Rockrider 5.0*

[image]

Photo from [priceminister.com](https://pmcdn.priceminister.com/photo/1133354276.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what you mean by "tray". That's not a standard term.  A cpiture would help, or if this is a matter of translation, perhaps telling us your native language and the term you use.  A thought: do you mean "chainring" as  they can come in threes and are round and flattish

Comment: Tray 1 as in gear 1 on your crank? Then most likely the front derailleur is not set up correctly. There are two small screws on top of the derailleur-fastening to the frame. These are to set the upper and lower limits of the derailleurs movement, so your chain doesn't get pushed of the cog-wheels.

Comment: @ChrisH In French we call it "les plateaux de vélos" I updated my question  accordingly, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, chainring then ([Sheldon has a glossary](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/eng-fren.html)).  And actually *plateau* as in the English *platter* (a big plate) is similar to calling big cogs *dinner plates* in English.

Comment: Shimano is by the way a brand of bicycle components. I'm guessing "the shimano" means front derailleur here, but that part could be more readable with correct terms.

Comment: @ojs Actually the brand of the front derailleur is Shimano so I think it looks correct to talk about Shimano because it's more accurate. But if not, feel free to correct me I'm glad to learn thanks for your feeback.

Comment: @Ced it's likely that rear derailleur, shifters and probably a lot of other parts are branded Shimano too, and it is not clear if you are referring to any of these. In idiomatic English, Shimano would refer to the company and would always be used without the "the". As written, the question sounds like you are asking if Shimano corporation has a kill switch that can be used to disable shifting on your bike.

Comment: @ojs I've updated the title accordingly

Comment: @Ced Saying that you have a problem with "the Shimano" is like saying that "The Dell doesn't work" when what you mean is the Dell keyboard attached to your Dell PC and Dell monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your front derailleur is probably just badly adjusted, although there may be issues with the shift cable or housing, or potentially even the shifter.

I'm not sure if by 'chainring 1' you mean the innermost or outermost. If outermost the cable is probably just too slack so the shifter cannot pull the cage outward enough. If innermost something is preventing the cage from swinging inwards, perhaps too much cable tension or something is jamming it.

Adjusting front derailleurs can be a bit tricky as cable tension, limit screws and alignment all potentially have to be dealt with. Park Tool has a good series of videos on derailleur adjustment that walk you through the steps and explain what each adjustment does. Front derailleur video is on [this page](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment). It's a good idea to go through these steps as if the derailleur has been knocked out of alignment no amount of adjustment will fix it.

You can work through that but it's not entirely guaranteed to produce success. If you are a real bike novice find a good local bike repair shop and have them fix the problem. It would be a good idea to have them check the rest of the bike at the same time, especially brakes and rear shifting.

Comment: Unless something weird has happened, the limit screws should already be in the right place. Don't touch them unless you have some reason to believe they're set wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by checking your shifters and cables are in good condition. If the cable is corroded, too much friction could be causing a problem.

Comment: I just realized that different version of the Rockrider 5.0 have been made, I guess I have the 2011 or 2012 version because I don't have any front suspension it is a rigid and not semi-rigid. I found a picture of the exact same one [here](https://pmcdn.priceminister.com/photo/1133354276.jpg)

Comment: This should really be a comment on the question, not an answer post, as it's asking questions not giving answers.

Comment: Your more than welcome to edit or delete as required

Comment: @swifty how am I supposed to comment on a question when the only option to post at the moment is to use the answer option, maybe the options should be the other way round, that way I could have indeed commented on the question.

Comment: I know, it feels a bit backwards to start with. In part it’s to reduce spam, any new answer gets noticed straight away and users can vote it up and down. Spam gets deleted pretty fast. But comments can go unnoticed and so don’t go away so easily. It also allows hopefully constructive feedback to new users. When you get to 50 rep you can comment every where and I see you’re nearly there.

Comment: @dank you now have over 50 rep and can comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36730)

Comment: @ojs the original was amended and modified and your still saying it's not an answer? Shall I just delete it?

Comment: @ojs also at the time the option to comment wasn't available, maybe read the comments above your one for clarification

Comment: This is still mostly comments about the original question and does not even mention adjustment

Comment: @DanK Your first three paragraphs are irrelevant: they do nothing to address the front derailleur issue and you should remove them. The last paragraph is good advice but perhaps you could expand it a little.

Comment: Edited to keep people happy

Answer (score -2):

There are two screws on top of your front derailleur:

[image]

They adjust, how far to the left/right your darailleur might move, and thus the chain. This is to prevent the chain from being shifted off the cogs, which is possible with the screws untightened and enough slack on the cable for shifting.

Vice versa, these also can prevent the derailleur from moving far enough to the right or left to push the chain onto the outer cogs. So, as in the picture, take a screwdriver and fiddle with the screws, until everything works. As stated, be careful not to loosen the screws too much, since this might result in the chain going off the cogs.

Comment: Erik, welcome. I think it would be better to suggest looking up guidance on how to adjust these ‘limit screws’ methodically, instead of implying slightly random fiddling. There must be instructions online. It’s certainly a good thing to look into.

Comment: Sure looking up is better/safer, but since we don't know OPs type of derailleur (and he probably also doesn't), fiddling and looking at examples is what we got.

Comment: Sorry, but 'fiddle with it until it works' is not the expert advice we're looking for here. The OP has already done that without success.

Comment: Well, feel free to guess without any further material provided by OP which screw he has to turn which direction how far. You can't. And if you don't like my wording, feel free to edit the post. Other than that, I stand by my post, since based on current data provided by OP, it is a valid answer.

Comment: @Erik It's not the wording that's the issue. The issue is that you're recommending blindly changing stuff without understanding what that stuff does. Worse, you're recommending blindly changing the wrong stuff. The limit screws should have been set correctly when the bike was built and there's no reason they should have moved since then -- unless somebody was blindly changing stuff without knowing what they were doing. It's possible that the limit screws need adjusting but it's the least likely option. Sorry but your answer is plain bad advice.

Comment: Well, then enlighten me and OP, what the right stuff would be. Based on OPs description and my experience I recommend the correct stuff.